# can I use pipes to communicate with existing application?

Tags: c++, inter-process-communicat

I was reading about pipes today, it seems an interesting for me to use it or to start about it.
but it's written there that the processes should be like a parent and child or client server and the communication will be between them.

there are some things I don't understand and before start I should be sure about them.

If I have a running process for example on my machine, and I want to send message to it, of course I can't control it, so how can I make it respond to my messages??
should I create the client and server and run them both?? 
Or the running process application can be a server for example and I can send some events to it??

if you can help me in this :)

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the running process is reading from stdin, you may write to /proc/the_pid/fd/0 to send your message.

Comment: Hi Manuel ,, could you please give some resources for using this ? I couldn't find one for that .. thanks :)